# Calender Library/Functions in C#

Tags: c#, calendar

I asked this question previously but worded it horribly and thus caused quite a stir.

Anyway. Within my current C# application I intend to include a calendar function, where the user can select a date and then information can be added and viewed based on that date. I'm simply wondering if any frameworks or libraries exist for C# that I could use in this project?

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean like `DateTime`, `TimeSpan`, `Calendar`?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not massively experienced with C#, I presume these are already libraries then?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using DevExpress for my projects.

If you're working with WPF I would recommend the [WPF Sheduler](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/wpf/scheduler/).

Comment: Would you recommend WPF over WindowsForms?